# Restrict Area to a given role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, membership, roles, area

I have an area setup in MVC2, called `Admin/`, which I want I only want Users who belong to the role "admins" to have access. I know I can decorate each of the methods with `[Authorize(Roles="admins")]`, but this seems tedious when your talking about multiple controllers with multiple actions.

Is there an better and cleaner way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define a base controller decorated with this attribute that all controllers in the area derive from.

Comment: For clarification, Darin's post implies that if you stick the [Authorized] attribute on the controller type itself, it's the equivalent of having applied it to every method in that controller (or a subclassed controller).