# Limiting Features in an asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wondering what is the best way of limiting features for accounts.

Say I have a free account and a premium account. How would I limit features off that only the premium account would get?

Right now the only thing I can think of is lots of "if statements" in the view.

Something of the items that I need to limit off are.

1. Jquery Ui Tabs(Premium account have one extra jquery ui tab - free has 4 but premium has 5).

So right now this would mean I need to if statements on for the unordered list to hide and one for the div that contains it. Maybe one if I am using ajax tabs.

1. hyper links. I have some hyper links that load up jquery dialogs that need to be hidden from free users again the only thing I can think of is an if statement.

These are the kind of things that I am anticipating that I need to hide from free accounts.

I think it is going to look nasty in the view with all these "if statements" however I don't want to have multiple views(one view for free account and one for premium) as that going to mean that I might have to start repeating code,(even with the use of partial views) gets more confusing as now I have more files to look through, more action results to create and determine which to use.

On one site I tried multiple views for account and action results and it did not work out to well.

So what are the best ways to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you'll want to add this logic to the controller, not the view.  You'll send some data to the view that signals to it that it should show the premium vs. standard features.  But the decisions on whether your in a premium or a standard state should be made in the controller.

So your views may have if statements, or some sort of logic to decide whether to show certain features or not, but they'll be based on this "accountlevel" data that you send from your controller.

If you're putting an "if" statement into a view, or many as in your case, you ought to think about writing an HTML helper instead.  That would clean up your code considerably.  Instead of writing multiple if's, you'd have something like HtmlHelper.JQueryTabs() in your view.  In the JQueryTabs method you'd have all your logic to output the appropriate HTML/Javascript depending on the Account Level.

Here's an article on [creating custom HTML helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Comment: Yes of course the decision would be made at the server level(possibly the business layer). The "if" statements in the view would just check to see if it should render that area. I was thinking about html helpers but sometimes I feel they make thing worse then better especially when it comes to styling stuff(you either have to hardcode the classes in the helper or pass them all through the helper)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a view model with two collections, one for links and one for tabs. The controller would populate these, based on the users' permissions. In the view, you could iterate round these collections and display them accordingly.

Comment: @harriyott- When you talk about links or tabs are you talking about the VM containing the actual html markup or are you talking about have a collection that I loop though in the view?

Comment: I'm talking about a collection that you loop through in the view. Perhaps a Dictionary<string, string> with the key being the link text and the value being the url

Comment: how about in cases where you just have one link that pops up a dialog box. Would you make that still a loop too or just do an if statement?

Comment: That could be either a bool property on the view model and an if in the view (although a ? : might be easier on the eye), or if that's still too messy, a partial view that accepts a couple of parameters that has the if inside it.  I guess it also depends on how you script it; if you have an onclick attribute in the link itself (which isn't the recommended way), you could put that in another property (maybe a Tuple or something), or the correct way, which is to have all the script in a separate .js file. In this case, the script can just check for the existence of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by creating roles under the membership provider. Then you can decorate either your entire controller or actions within it along the lines of:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Premium")]
public virtual ActionResult ShowPremiumContent()
{
    return View();
}
```

there are some good resources online that give different approaches to the same end game:

[Restrict Area to a given role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291385/restrict-area-to-a-given-role)

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/01/04/authorizing-access-via-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-without-magic-strings.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasthedeuce/archive/2009/06/25/133056.aspx

Comment: I will be using Authorize attribute reguardless but I don't know if that will solve my problem(at least not the way I want it). For instance I have a dialog with a form in it split into tabs(its all in the same form though). Free accounts might see one less tab but when submitting it will all go the same controller minus the information for the non existent tab in the free account. So if I put a authorize tag that needs a premium account then I going to need to action methods to send it the right area(one for free and one for premium). This is something I don't want to do as now........

Comment: I need to have some logic to figure out which action method to send it through the ajax. I probably will need to extract those part out into their own scripts and make changes to them and load up the right script when the account loads and stuff like that.

Comment: chobo2 - gotcha. so you really need an interface (by this, i mean a code interface rather than a concrete strongly typed class) that differentiates between free and premium at the controller/service level. i also think the html helpers with the roles examination may well be a good route to go with perhaps a code implementation that examines the roles in a service class

Comment: @ jim - Can you elaborate more on the interface. How would that look in the view? Are you talking about making a interface of the VM?